# setInterval + for Loop skipping iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, settimeout

I have a lot of code to my current project so I will do my best to explain the very strange issue I am having.

I have an array of arrays called `proDatabase` which is 126 entries in length, each entry being an array of 4 entries in length.

I have a button, that when clicked, starts a `setInterval` function every `1.05` seconds to run a function called "`getScore`"

`getScore` consists of an ajax call to an API, which returns a JSON object, and I gather a bunch of data from that object before performing a calculation function called `calculateHmc`.

`calculateHmc` performs a big calculation and pushes values to a global array. The console then logs the values of this array to show that it was successful.

The problem I am having is that when I run this script which takes about 2.5 minutes (126 entries x ~1.05 seconds per entry), the results change from run to run. What I mean by this is sometimes it will successfully get an array for entry 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, but not 10 and 11, whereas another time it will get an array for 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, but not 6 and 9.

I thought maybe I was making AJAX calls too fast, but I have tried setting the delay to 2-5 even 9 seconds and the problem still persists.

I was initially using a for loop with a setTimeout delay and changed to setInterval because I thought it would probably be better for making AJAX calls.

Here is the meat and potatoes:

```
var proDatabase = [
    ["fredy122", 266, 19286794, "euw"],
    ["soeren", 103, 47199162, "na"],
    ["voyboy", 84, 19134540, "na"],
    ["krepo", 12, 19307647, "euw"],
    ["kiwikid", 32, 24332462, "na"],
    ["froggen", 34, 29762147, "na"],
    ["FnaticYellOwStaR", 1, 254943, "euw"],
    ["dingdongchingchong", 22, 38332654, "kr"],
    ["kiwikid", 432, 24332462, "na"],
    ["wingsofdeathx", 268, 19660288, "na"],
    ["liquidxpecial", 201, 19199530, "na"],
    ["aphromoo", 53, 442232, "na"],
    ["wingsofdeathx", 63, 19660288, "na"],
    ["sneaky", 51, 1621, "na"],
    ["easyhoon", 69, 14080738, "kr"],
    ["azingy", 31, 22479740, "na"],
    ["jin air cpt jack", 42, 1560617, "kr"],
    ["voyboy", 122, 19134540, "na"],
    ["shiphtur", 131, 19967304, "na"],
    ["arrow", 119, 9161207, "kr"],
    ["calitrlolz8", 36, 21059607, "na"],
    ["svenskeren", 245, 37220473, "eune"],
    ["meteos", 60, 44008519, "na"],
    ["theoddone", 28, 60783, "na"],
    ["jin air chaser", 81, 7941870, "kr"],
    ["azingy", 9, 22479740, "na"],
    ["jin air trace", 114, 35214500, "na"],
    ["xpeke", 105, 47409145, "na"],
    ["overpow", 3, 30968712, "euw"],
    ["fredy122", 41, 19286794, "euw"],
    ["darien", 86, 295022, "euw"],
    ["jin air cpt jack", 150, 1560617, "kr"],
    ["theoddone", 79, 60783, "na"],
    ["skt t1 bengi", 104, 1255867, "kr"],
    ["dyrus", 120, 5908, "na"],
    ["voyboy", 74, 19134540, "na"],
    ["dyrus", 39, 5908, "na"],
    ["smoothie", 40, 20823651, "na"],
    ["watch", 59, 1241252, "kr"],
    ["voyboy", 24, 19134540, "na"],
    ["ryu", 126, 3617422, "kr"],               //["ryu", 126, 3617422, "kr"],
    ["doublelift", 222, 20132258, "na"],
    ["wildturtl", 429, 42060215, "na"],
    ["C9 Lemon", 43, 44979325, "na"],
    ["fredy122", 30, 19286794, "euw"],
    ["voyboy", 38, 19134540, "na"],
    ["nien", 55, 35717979, "na"],
    ["rng alex ichy", 10, 65009177, "na"],
    ["fredy122", 85, 19286794, "euw"],
    ["voyboy", 121, 19134540, "na"],
    ["renegade maple", 96, 31804754, "na"],
    ["c9 jensen", 7, 68479082, "na"],
    ["svenskeren", 64, 37220473, "eune"],
    ["krepo", 89, 19307647, "euw"],
    ["marin", 127, 23041646, "kr"],
    ["img steeel4ckv2", 236, 69399083, "na"],
    ["overpow", 117, 30968712, "euw"],
    ["kami", 99, 4442388, "br"],
    ["voyboy", 90, 19134540, "na"],
    ["theoddone", 54, 60783, "na"],
    ["dyrus", 57, 5908, "na"],
    ["choi insec", 11, 1567183, "kr"],
    ["theoddone", 21, 60783, "na"],
    ["overpow", 82, 30968712, "euw"],
    ["aphromoo", 25, 442232, "na"],
    ["fnaticyellowstar", 267, 254943, "euw"],
    ["suryD", 75, 89197, "na"],
    ["xpecial", 111, 21744791, "na"],
    ["h0r0", 76, 2191624, "kr"],
    ["crumbzz", 56, 38789432, "na"],
    ["crumbzz", 20, 38789432, "na"],
    ["theoddone", 2, 60783, "na"],
    ["pobelter", 61, 2648, "na"],
    ["azingy", 80, 22479740, "na"],
    ["voyboy", 78, 19134540, "na"],
    ["lustboy", 133, 58849083, "na"],
    ["unstoppable move", 33, 68159251, "na"],
    ["theoddone", 421, 60783, "na"],
    ["dyrus", 58, 5908, "na"],
    ["svenskeren", 107, 37220473, "euw"],
    ["zionspartan", 92, 19738326, "na"],
    ["dyrus", 68, 5908, "na"],
    ["hide on bush", 13, 4460427, "kr"],
    ["loulex", 113, 20050482, "euw"],
    ["fnaticyellowstar", 35, 254943, "euw"],
    ["lustboy", 98, 58849083, "na"],
    ["theoddone", 102, 60783, "na"],
    ["skt t1 bengi", 27, 1255867, "kr"],
    ["kev1n", 14, 50333030, "eune"],
    ["jin air cpt jack", 15, 1560617, "kr"],
    ["nightblue3", 72, 33320460, "na"],
    ["godpiglet", 37, 65409090, "na"],
    ["adrian", 16, 3267, "na"],
    ["vizicsacsi", 50, 33779494, "na"],
    ["overpow v1", 134, 19479122, "euw"],
    ["voyboy", 223, 19134540, "na"],
    ["kami", 91, 4442388, "br"],
    ["dunno lol", 44, 37802535, "euw"],
    ["overpow", 17, 30968712, "euw"],
    ["aphromoo", 412, 442232, "na"],
    ["sneaky", 18, 1621, "na"],
    ["yellowstar", 48, 42323523, "eune"],
    ["save", 23, 19134540, "na"],
    ["shiphtur", 4, 19967304, "na"],
    ["wildturtle", 29, 521955, "na"],
    ["trick2g", 77, 19975245, "na"],
    ["i am bjerg", 6, 49159160, "na"],
    ["turtle the cat", 110, 18991200, "na"],
    ["wildturtle", 67, 521955, "na"],
    ["fly", 45, 1570144, "kr"],
    ["dodo8", 161, 19245823, "na"],
    ["crumbzz", 254, 38789432, "na"],
    ["froggen", 112, 29762147, "na"],
    ["pain kamikat", 8, 479257, "br"],
    ["azingy", 106, 22479740, "na"],
    ["nightblue3", 19, 3320460, "na"],
    ["nightblue3", 62, 33320460, "na"],
    ["pain kamikat", 101, 479257, "br"],
    ["nightblue3", 5, 3320460, "na"],
    ["dunamis or shiphtur", 157, 44989349, "na"],
    ["c9 jensen", 83, 68479082, "na"],
    ["theoddone", 154, 60783, "na"],
    ["hide on bush", 238, 4460427, "kr"],
    ["theoddone", 115, 60783, "na"],
    ["korean characters... fly", 26, 2706560, "kr"],
    ["xpooks", 143, 174035, "euw"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#sendButton").click(function () {

    var counter = 0;
    var n = setInterval(function () {

        var summonerName = proDatabase[counter][0];
        var summonerId = proDatabase[counter][2];
        var championNumber = proDatabase[counter][1];
        var region = proDatabase[counter][3];

        console.log(summonerId + " " + championNumber);
        // console.log("Initializing function...");

        getScore(summonerId, championNumber, region, summonerName);
        // console.log("passed the getScore function")
        console.log(counter);
        counter++;
        if (counter == 127) {
            clearInterval(n);
        }
    }, 1050, counter);

});
});

function getScore(summonerId, championNumber,  region, summonerName) {

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://' + region + '.api.pvp.net/api/lol/' + region + '/v2.2/matchhistory/' + summonerId + '?championIds=' + championNumber + '&queueType=NORMAL_5x5_BLIND,NORMAL_5x5_DRAFT,RANKED_SOLO_5x5,RANKED_PREMADE_5x5,NORMAL_5x5_DRAFT,RANKED_TEAM_5x5&beginIndex=0&endIndex=5&api_key=***********************',
    success: function (data, state) {

        /*  if(state == "success"){
            console.log("OBJECT RETURNED (SUCCESS)");
        }else{
            console.log("SUMMONER COULD NOT BE FOUND. LIKELY WRONG REGION. CHECK LOLKING");
        } */

        console.log("LOOKING UP GAMES FOR " + summonerName + " WITH A SUMMONER ID OF " + summonerId + "IN REGION "+ region + "FOR CHAMPION NUMBER " + championNumber);

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            //v1.1.0

            if (data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.firstBloodKill == true){
                firstBloodArray[i] = 1;
            }else{
                firstBloodArray[i] = 0;
            }

            if (data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.firstTowerKill == true){
                firstTowerArray[i] = 1;
            }else{
                firstTowerArray[i] = 0;
            }

            if (data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.firstTowerKill == true){
                firstInhibitorArray[i] = 1;
            }else{
                firstInhibitorArray[i] = 0;
            }

            damageDealtArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalDamageDealt;
            healingDealtArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalHeal;
            damageTakenArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalDamageTaken;
            inhibitorArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.inhibitorKills;
            towerArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.towerKills;

            //timeline arrays

            tl_arr_cspm_zero_ten[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.zeroToTen;
            tl_arr_cspm_ten_twenty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.tenToTwenty;

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty != undefined) {
                tl_arr_cspm_twenty_thirty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty;
            }else{
                tl_arr_cspm_twenty_thirty[i] = 0
            }

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd != undefined) {
                tl_arr_cspm_thirty_end[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd;
            }else{
                tl_arr_cspm_thirty_end[i] = 0
            }

            tl_arr_xppm_zero_ten[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.zeroToTen;
            tl_arr_xppm_ten_twenty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.tenToTwenty;

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty != undefined) {
                tl_arr_xppm_twenty_thirty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty;
            }else{
                tl_arr_xppm_twenty_thirty[i] = 0;
            }

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd != undefined){
                tl_arr_xppm_thirty_end[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd;
            }else{
                tl_arr_xppm_thirty_end[i] = 0;
            }


            tl_arr_gpm_zero_ten[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.zeroToTen;
            tl_arr_gpm_ten_twenty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.tenToTwenty;

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty != undefined){
                tl_arr_gpm_twenty_thirty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty;
            }else{
                tl_arr_gpm_twenty_thirty[i] = 0;
            }

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd != undefined){
                tl_arr_gpm_thirty_end[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd;
            }else{
                tl_arr_gpm_thirty_end[i] = 0;
            }


            //v1.0.2

            csArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled;
            assistArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.assists;
            killArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.kills;
            gameTimeArray[i] = data.matches[i].matchDuration;
            championArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].championId;
            deathArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.deaths;
            jungleCSArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle;
            counterJungleCSArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle;
            roleArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.role;
            laneArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.lane;
            crowdControlArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalTimeCrowdControlDealt;

            switch (roleArray[i]) {
                case "DUO":
                case "SOLO":
                    //assumes top lane duo player or solo mid or solo top
                    calculateHmc(championNumber, 1.33, 1, 0.5, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 5, 0.5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 3, 1.5, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,  i);
                    break;
                case "DUO_CARRY":
                    //assumes bot lane adc
                    calculateHmc(championNumber, 1.33, 1, 0.5, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 5, 0.5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, i);
                    break;
                case "DUO_SUPPORT":
                    //assumes bot lane support
                    calculateHmc(championNumber, 1.33, 1, 0.75, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 0.5, 5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 0.25, 3.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, i);
                    break;
                case "NONE":
                    //assumes jungle, check lane
                    calculateHmc(championNumber, 1.33, 1, 0.5, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 2, 2.5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 1.5, 1.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, i);
                    break;
            }
        // console.log("loop worked for iteration " + i);
        }
    }
});


function calculateHmc(cNum, aF,bF,cF,dF,eF,fF,gF,hF,iF,kF,lF,mF,nF,oF,pF,qF,rF,sF,tF,uF,vF,wF,xF,yF,zF,aaF,bbF,ccF, n) {

//aF = first blood
//bF = kills
//cF = assists
//dF = creeps slain
//eF = jungle creeps slain
//fF = counter jungle creeps slain
//gF = gold earned
//hF = cc dealt in seconds
//iF = deaths
//jF = neutral monster kills
//kF = tower kills
//lF = inhibitor kills
//mF = first tower kill
//nF = first inhib kill
//oF = damage taken
//pF = damage dealt
//qF = healing dealt

//rF = creeps slain per minute, time = 0min to 10min
//sF = creeps slain per minute, time = 10min to 20min
//tF = creeps slain per minute, time = 20min to 30min
//uF = creeps slain per minute, time = 30min to end

//vF = xp gain per minute, time = 0min to 10min
//wF = xp gain per minute, time = 10min to 20min
//xF = xp gain per minute, time = 20min to 30min
//yF = xp gain per minute, time = 30min to end

//zF = gold gain per minute, time = 0min to 10 min
//aaF = gold gain per minute, time = 10min to 20 min
//bbF = gold gain per minute, time = 20min to 30 min
//ccF = gold gain per minute, time = 30min to end


var pvpFactor = (
    ((aF * firstBloodArray[n]) +                                        // PVP FACTOR CONSISTS OF ((FIRST BLOOD KILL + NORMAL KILLS + ASSISTS) / (DEATHS + 1))/(GAMETIME / 60sec)
     (bF * killArray[n]) +
     (cF * assistArray[n])) /
     (iF * (deathArray[n] + 1)))/(gameTimeArray[n] / 3600);

pvpFactor = pvpFactor.toFixed(2);
pvpFactorArray.push(pvpFactor);
// console.log(pvpFactorArray);

var pveFactor =                                                         // PVE FACTOR CONSISTS OF 3 FACTORS WITHIN ITSELF, ADDED TOGETHER, SO, (FACTOR 1 + FACTOR 2 + FACTOR 3) = pveFactor.
    ((dF * csArray[n]) +
    (eF * jungleCSArray[n]) +                                           // FACTOR 1: MINIONS KILLED + JUNGLE MINIONS KILLED + COUNTERJUNGLE MINIONS KILLED, ALL DIVIDED BY GAMETIME IN UNITS: MINUTES ***NEEDS A SCALING FACTOR***
    (fF * counterJungleCSArray[n])) / ((gameTimeArray[n]) / 60) +
                                                                        // +
    ((rF * tl_arr_cspm_zero_ten[n]) +
    (sF * tl_arr_cspm_ten_twenty[n]) +                                  // FACTOR 2: MINIONS KILLED PER MINUTE @ 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-end ALL ADDED TOGETHER ***NEEDS A SCALING FACTOR***
    (tF * tl_arr_cspm_twenty_thirty[n]) +
    (uF * tl_arr_cspm_thirty_end[n])) +
                                                                        // +
    ((vF * tl_arr_xppm_zero_ten[n]) +
     (wF * tl_arr_xppm_ten_twenty[n]) +                                    // FACTOR 3: EXPERIENCE GAINED PER MINUTE @ 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-end ALL ADDED TOGETHER ***NEEDS A SCALING FACTOR***
     (xF * tl_arr_xppm_twenty_thirty[n]) +
     (yF * tl_arr_xppm_thirty_end[n]));

pveFactor = pveFactor.toFixed(2);
pveFactorArray.push(pveFactor);
// console.log(pveFactorArray);

var auxFactor =
    ((hF * crowdControlArray[n]) +                                      // AUX FACTOR CONSISTS OF (CC DEALT + DAMAGE DEALT + HEALING DEALT) / DAMAGE TAKEN / GAMETIME(min)
     (pF * damageDealtArray[n]) +
     (qF * healingDealtArray[n])) +

    ((kF * towerArray[n]) +
    (lF * inhibitorArray[n]) +
    (mF * firstTowerArray[n]) +
    (nF * firstInhibitorArray[n])) +

    ((zF * tl_arr_gpm_zero_ten[n]) +
    (aaF * tl_arr_gpm_ten_twenty[n]) +
    (bbF * tl_arr_gpm_twenty_thirty[n]) +
    (ccF * tl_arr_gpm_thirty_end[n])) /

    ((oF * damageTakenArray[n]) /
    (gameTimeArray[n] / 60));


auxFactor = auxFactor.toFixed(2);
auxFactorArray.push(auxFactor);
// console.log(auxFactorArray);

var rawHMC = (1000 * pvpFactor) + (2 * pveFactor) + (0.01 * auxFactor);
hmcArray.push(rawHMC);
// console.log(hmcArray);

if(hmcArray.length == 5){

    psdb_pvp.push([[cNum], pvpFactorArray]);
    //console.log("PVP FACTOR ARRAY")
    //console.log(pvpFactorArray);
    psdb_pve.push([[cNum], pveFactorArray]);
    //console.log("PVE FACTOR ARRAY")
    //console.log(pveFactorArray);
    psdb_aux.push([[cNum], auxFactorArray]);
    //console.log("AUX FACTOR ARRAY")
    //console.log(auxFactorArray);
    psdb_hmc.push([[cNum], hmcArray]);


    //console.log(psdb_pvp);
    //console.log(psdb_pve);
    //console.log(psdb_aux);
    console.log(psdb_hmc);

    pvpFactorArray = [];
    pveFactorArray = [];
    auxFactorArray = [];
    hmcArray = [];

}






}
```

This my console output for a successful array entry. here you can see it gets and pushes an array when `counter == 9`.:

[image]

And here is an example of when it skips this for some random reason:

[image]

No code changed between these two runs. All I did was refresh the page and click the `sendButton` again.

I realize its a lot to take in, but I didn't want to simplify my code and accidently exclude something that may be the problem, because I really have no idea why this is happening.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You have to wait `getScore` to finish before updating the counter, try using callbacks or Promises

Comment: There's a lot of code to look through there, but one thing I would suggest is to use setTimeout instead of setInterval. However, instead of just putting the setTimeouts in a for loop, make the callback of setTimeout and the ajax calls create the next one, after performing all of the other data handling functions. That way the various timeout/ajax functions cannot possibly overlap. The downside to this is that you may find that the time between ajax calls is not 100% regular, but I think it will be close enough for you purposes.

Comment: @charlietfl I believe I did show the interval loop and ajax calls, just look under the array.

Comment: @RodrigoAssis thank you I will check out what these are.

Paul thanks as well, i need to look into what a callback is.

Comment: Why are you passing `counter` as an additional argument to `setInterval`, when the function doesn't take any arguments?

Comment: i missed that but there is way to much code there...scale it down to only relevant code, replace any of the html parsing and dom insertion with comment

Comment: @Vranvs Take a look at [this sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/y11nens0/) and see if it gives you a hint

Comment: Thanks guys, I will check this out ASAP

Answer (score 0):

While this is by no means a complete answer, here is an example of how to use callbacks/setTimeout to prevent conflicts. In this example we send our ajax request, wait until a successful response is received, process the data, and only then do we set the timeout to call the next ajax request.

```
function getScore(summonerId, championNumber,  region, summonerName) {
    $.ajax({
       dataType: "json",
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://' + region + '.api.pvp.net/api/lol/' + region + '/v2.2/matchhistory/' + summonerId + '?championIds=' + championNumber + '&queueType=NORMAL_5x5_BLIND,NORMAL_5x5_DRAFT,RANKED_SOLO_5x5,RANKED_PREMADE_5x5,NORMAL_5x5_DRAFT,RANKED_TEAM_5x5&beginIndex=0&endIndex=5&api_key=***********************',
       success: function (data, state) {
           //process my data here
           //after processing my data, get my new parameters (using counter?)
           //and call getScore again
           setTimeout(function(){ getScore(my, incremented, parameters, here); }, 1050); //call getScore in 1.05s
       }
    });
}
```